# Unable to display gridview data on search

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I was able to retrieve data from the database when the page was loaded showing all the data in the database so far. but when i was going to use the text box and search button i got an error saying "ERROR: MUST DECLARE THE SCALAR VARIABLE @MRF_NO". Is there any problem with my code?? I will post the codes.

**C#**

```
private void searchsumm()
    {
        database db = new database();
        string database = db.MRF();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(database))
        {
            con.Open();

            string query = "Select MRF_No, BU, Dept,ReqByDept_Mngr FROM MRF_Details";
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con))

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text.Trim()))
            {
                query += " WHERE ContactName LIKE @MRF_No + '%'";
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MRF_No", txtSearch.Text.Trim());
            }

            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt); //Error: Must declare the scalar variable "@MRF_No".
                smry.DataSource = dt;
                smry.DataBind();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

**ASP.NET**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" ReadOnly="false" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>  
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <asp:Button ID="searchdb" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Search" onclick="btnsummary"/>
            </div>

            <div class="row-space"></div>

        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="smry" CssClass="list-group" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true"  >

            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="MRF_No" HeaderText="MRF No" SortExpression="MRF_No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BU" HeaderText="Business Unit" SortExpression="BU" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Dept" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Dept" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ReqByDept_Mngr" HeaderText="Request By" SortExpression="ReqByDept_Mngr" />
            </Columns>

        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Check the value of `txtSearch.Text`. It is probably not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your query is wrong in the **where** clause:

```
query += " WHERE ContactName LIKE @MRF_No + '%'";
```

It should be:

```
query += " WHERE ContactName LIKE '%' + @MRF_No + '%'";
```

Also, I think you need to create your **SqlDataAdapter** passing the command you just built, so that the query includes the parameters you defined.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(com))
{
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     sda.Fill(dt);
     smry.DataSource = dt;
     smry.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be syntax issue. Can you see if below works:

```
query += " WHERE ContactName LIKE @MRF_No";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MRF_No", "%" + txtSearch.Text.Trim() + "%");
```

Comment: How does this work without '' around the text?

query += " WHERE ContanctName LIKE '%' + @MRF_No + '%'

Comment: Gabitu, I think adding ' when the command is turned into sql query is handled by AddWithValue method. Whatever is passed as the second parameter gets enclosed in '. Thats just how I think it works; couldn't find anything in the official  doc about that part.